# Fatal error: Class 'Mongo' not found in

Tags: php, mongodb, wamp

I need to use Mongodb in my PHP script.

So I have installed **php_mongodb.dll** from **php_mongodb-1.2.5-5.6-ts-vc11-x64.zip** into "C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.25\ext\".
I have added **extension.dll** in **php.ini**.

When I run **php.exe**, there is nothing wrong, any warning... But **Mongodb** doesn't appear in the list of php extensions (**phpinfo()**).

In addition, my index.php returns "**Fatal error: Class 'Mongo' not found in C:\wamp64\www\scripts\index.php on line 47**".
The line 47 : `$con = new Mongo(); # localhost:27017`

- Version Apache :2.4.23
- Version de PHP :5.6.25
- OS : Windows 10
- Wamp : Version 3.0.6 - 64bit

I have already tried **php_mongodb.dll** or **php_mongo.dll**, different other versions... But now, I have any idea.

If someone has solution to propose, he will be welcome.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution... The right dll !

In fact, I must use **[MongoDB PHP Driver on Windows](http://php.net/manual/fr/mongodb.installation.windows.php)**.
Then add **extension=php_mongodb.dll** into **php.ini**.
And download the corresponding file from [mongodb 1.2.5](http://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb/1.2.5/windows), in this case 5.6 Thread Safe (TS) x64.

php.exe shows no warning and the line 47 (`$con = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017"); # localhost:27017`) works correctly.

Don't forget to restart services.

Hopefully this solution will serve...

Answer (score 0):

To whom may concern !

I migrated a system:

- PHP 5.6 to 7.2
- Mongo Server 2.6 to 4.4
- Driver 1.3 to 1.9

Do not replace `new Mongo`, create an alias instead. This is what I did.

- Original:

```
$this->connectionDB = new Mongo('...');
```

- Added:

```
use MongoDB\Driver\Manager as Mongo;

$this->connectionDB = new Mongo('...');
```

And you don't need to fix anything.